# How can I make a "sum" column for groups of previous rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have a table and each in each row I have an amount, how would I display the sum of groups of rows?
Example:
A 100
A 100
A 100
B 120

I am trying to create a 3rd column that has the 300 (100+100+100) in the middle of these 100/100/100 cells so as to be clear that the number in each cell in the third column is the sum of the previous.
I tried using `rowspan` but it does not work. How can I achieve this? Example:

```
<html>  
<body>  
<table>  
    <tr>  
        <td>A</td>  
        <td>B</td>  
        <td>100</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td>A</td>  
        <td>B</td>  
        <td>100</td>  
        <td rowspan="2">$300</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td>A</td>  
        <td>B</td>  
        <td>100</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td>C</td>  
        <td>B</td>  
        <td>100</td>  
    </tr>   
</table>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is the right way to do complex stuff like this to compute your sum? Is it not possible to do that before in server side and just display the result with JS?

Comment: @sdespont:I don't want to actually calculate the sum.Originally I wanted to but it was too complicated.I only want to display the sum which I can get precalculated.So it is only a display issue I have.This seems to be like a reasonable presentation unless there is a better/easier option to display the sums

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but this may be an alignment problem. Set `border="1"` on your table and you'll see why.

Try:

```
<td rowspan="2" valign="bottom">$300</td>
```

Comment: It needed `valign="top"`.Setting borders helped on this.But it works in this specific set.If I have groups of odd/even rows to sum over I don't think this works

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what your issue is, but here is a JS OOP solution for getting the summ of cells (assuming that your table is sorted):

```
(function () {
  // Helper
  function $(selector) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  }

  function Group(name, row) {
    this.name = name;
    this.summ = 0;
    this.length = 0;
    this.cell = document.createElement('td');

    row.appendChild(this.cell);
  }

  Group.prototype._update = function () {
    this.cell.textContent = this.summ;
    this.cell.setAttribute('rowspan', this.length);
  };

  Group.prototype.add = function (value) {
    this.summ += value;
    this.length++;

    this._update();
  };

  var group = null;

  $('#summup tr').forEach(function (row) {
    var name = row.children[0].textContent;
    var value = parseFloat(row.children[1].textContent, 10);

    if (!group || group.name !== name) {
      group = new Group(name, row);
    }

    group.add(value);
  });
})();
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iSATiMus/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Why does it matter if the table is sorted or not?

Comment: @Jim this is how my algorithm works: if it meets new name in the first cell, it creates new group. See this example of unsorted table: http://jsbin.com/iSATiMus/4/edit?html,js,output